# Bootstrap input-group text without button taking half the space

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I don't know if that is a supposed behaviour or not, but I've come across something weird with `input-group`. When there is just a text input inside it, the textbox is smaller than when there is a button. See the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20367/

Is that normal ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you´re not grouping anything I *think* this is to be considered normal. By adding a input addon it extends.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/20370/

```
<div class="input-group">
    <!-- INPUT GROUP ADDON -->
    <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Also read http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups

Comment: The idea was to have a list with an 'add' button on the last element only; so if an element is not the last, remove the either the `span` or just the `button` from the DOM. I realised I didn't need to do it this way but I'm still curious. I agree that a group with only one element in it is kinda pointless but it's still a weird behaviour.

Comment: If only the last div has a button, why use .input-group on the ones not using the purpose of .input-group? Simply remove the css-class.

Comment: because the divs are created dynamically, depending on a list that can change. So the last one isn't the same all the time

Comment: How are they created? Via ajax? If so, then use javascript to add the class when done. If you build it in a for-loop then add it in the last itteration. Key is to not add it to every div.

Comment: Via AngularJS' `ng-repeat` directive. But that doesn't matter here. The thing that I find really odd is that in an input-group, a textbox without anything else takes up only half the space. That's not how it should behave IMO. Anyways as said in my first comment I solved my problem; but I'm still curious.